# Good APIs for optical character recognition Chinese<->English characters?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, html, ocr

1) What are good APIs for OCR (optical character recognition) for Chinese characters?

2) We know many exist for English ones, and some are documented on StackOverflow.

Which are good ones for web-centric development, though?  In other words, we want to build a service based on JSON and Javascript.  Ideally, we would send imagesto some API and receive a JSON response with all the characters embedded inside the images.

Are there specific APIs for Android or iOS, if we decide to perform the OCR natively on the device as opposed to through a central server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.Abbyy.com is going to be the best place to look.  Their mobile OCR overview can be found here - http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/features#Section_5;  It supports Chinese.

There are some web base services based on the Abbyy engine - http://www.wisetrend.com - They will charge based on volume but may be a good way to start out.